# Strange Errors with Headset

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, usb-3

My new headset (a logitech h340) is failing to work in an extremely bizarre way.

My old one (a logitech h540) broke. I'm assuming faulty wiring, as it connects and disconnects when I move it certain ways. I confirmed this on different computers.

I also confirmed that my new headset works. It's only on this computer.

I plug it in and try to run the test sound in playback device, and I get this brief almost honking sound and it stops abruptly. But it believes that it's still playing. If I unplug the headset it still shows up.

I might hear a brief sound, before they go out quickly with other programs.

I've tried plugging the new headset into different USB ports and I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

After a number of ordeals, such as the hard drive being rendered inaccessible, being unable to get a repair disk or USB, and having to reinstall windows...

Tried plugging it into a different port. My going theory is that it has to do with USB-2.0 vs 3.0.